# Reason filtering irregularity in close vote review page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I occasionally see "exact duplicate" questions appear on the review page despite having configured my filters to exclude it. This seems to happen when a question has close votes for multiple reasons, i.e. "exact duplicate" or "too localized".

I think the filtering is a great idea otherwise!

**Update**

Okay, so this is by design; guessing the query just asserts something like this (oversimplified) condition:

```
WHERE reason IN (list of checked reasons)
```

Is there a chance this could be turned into something like this?

```
WHERE reason IN (list of checked reasons) 
AND reason NOT IN (list of unchecked reasons)
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently, review filters ensure that each post matches each one of your *checked* (i.e. checkbox is checked) criteria, but do not ensure that each post does not match each *unchecked* criterion.

A post that has been closed both as "exact duplicate" and "too localized" still matches your filter, since "too localized" is checked.