# How to make close-review queue less thankless

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

It's been hovering around 50k for months now.  I'll give the benefit of the doubt and assume these questions are well-prioritized so that the totally irrelevant-to-close questions according to some business logic.  (Note:  I'm not sure if this is true.)

Anyway, here's why I think this is an active problem:  Reviewing closes is an extraordinarily thankless task at the moment.  I put in my 1k for the gold badge a while ago - mostly on the very quick "off topic" votes - and thanks to my work the queue has gone from 50.8k to 50.6k.  For me to continue working on this problem, there is no rep, no badge, and *no impact on queue size*.  That last one is literal - 50 a day leads to 10 questions closed on close votes, and that isn't a significant digit in the number "50.6k".

So the goliath queue means people like me, who like getting s*** done and seeing empty lists of things to do and such, are rather actively deterred.  I suspect this queue would move much faster if at any given time it were limited to 1000 and some offline task sneakily added more work to a few hours after it reaches bottom.

No concrete proposal yet.  Everything I can think of is kind of "eh," and I'd rather this question over some chance for momentum than amass downvotes based on my poor solution set thus far.

Comment: What would happen if we simply _reset_ the queue, simply dropping every task that is there (older than x)?

Comment: @JanDvorak: What does that accomplish? It gives you on-paper satisfaction, but that's it.

Comment: @Manishearth I am more likely to participate in a queue that has a decent chance of getting empty than in a queue that is hopelessly growing.

Comment: Amusingly, I ran across your question in the Close Review Queue here on meta. Coincidence? I think not.

Comment: I agree this is a big problem. I have very little motivation to go through that queue because it a time-sink with no feeling of reward. I don't even think additional badges would motivate me. Maybe being awarded a small amount of rep? Your suggestion of only putting in a thousand at a time to allow to empty periodically is psychologically tricky but I think it would actually work on me.

Comment: What if we just made it possible to get more than one reviewer badge per review task? We couldn't well give much else.

Comment: @Seth, what about [mugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198627/proposed-contest-for-close-review-queue-posse)?

Comment: @BenLee Mugs would be cool, although that would be a lot of mugs ;P

Comment: 84K close reviews; it hasn't gotten any less thankless.

Comment: related: [Close Votes review: I'm going on a strike!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208220/165773)

Comment: the problem has been (at last) acknowledged and addresed by SE team: [Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions "feature request at MSO")

Answer (score 16):

The close queue is not only thankless, it is also time consuming.  It takes far longer to process a 'Close' review (for me, on average) than, say, a 'Suggested Edit' review.  I seldom reach 40 'close' reviews in a day because it is too depressing an exercise.

There was a period, maybe a month or so ago, when the number was down under 50k.

Basically, we'll have to keep plugging away at it.

I do get the impression that today's 'close' votes get processed before older ones — I seem to get questions asked today before older ones.  I also find them easier to leave open; the questioner hasn't yet had a chance to go and fix the question up, so leaving it open gives them a bit more time, reducing the 'premature close' problem.

Comment: Well, fwiw, the off topic ones tend to be quite quick.

Comment: Given the filters I use, I don't see many off-topic questions; partly, perhaps, because they aren't on the highest traffic sections of the site.

Comment: Would a “right of appeal” against a close vote, make you more likely to vote to close a newer questions?

Comment: @IanRingrose: probably not, no.

Answer (score 6):

It might be helpful if you could see how many questions there are in the queue that fit your filtering options.

That way a reviewer might focus on a seldomly used tag with a chance of completely empting the queue for that tag.

Comment: related question: [What difficulties could be there to show amount of posts that match my filter in the SO CV queue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209632/165773)