# What difficulties could be there to show amount of posts that match my filter in the SO CV queue?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close, statistics

I am interested to track the progress in "my neck of woods", that is to roughly estimate how many posts in the queue match the filter I selected (FWIW, my current filter is "primarily opinion-based" and according to Shog, recently queue had [6,345 posts that match it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/209404/revisions)).

> [image]

Taking into account that I may use filter settings for various close reasons and tags, what could be difficulties to show / refresh this kind of stats? Could there be performance or UX or other problems?

---

Note similar idea was mentioned in an answer in [How to make close-review queue less thankless](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208615/165773)

> It might be helpful if you could see how many questions there are in the queue that fit your filtering options.
>
> That way a reviewer might focus on a seldom used tag with a chance of completely emptying the queue for that tag.

Another answer pointing to this is in [Fuzzy the number of questions in the close review queue...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208370/165773)

> Counter proposal: why not show how many questions are awaiting review in *my* part of the site...
>
> So if I've filtered the queue to [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) the number of close votes isn't 92.5k...

My question differs from above in that I am specifically interested to learn about what could prevent this from getting done.

Comment: for the record, a pragmatically limited variation for "filter related stats" is provided in the answer in [Easy close review queue filtering interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209778/165773) -- _"Keeping those counts up-to-date is expensive, so we'd probably have to limit them to the broadest possible filters..."_

Comment: If we can't have this for implementation reasons, maybe we can at least [get some totals per tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224385/191131)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the huge number of possible filters, I imagine it would be next to impossible to cache the total number (unlike the total number for each queue). The SO team tends to not like un-cached queries running on popular pages as it can drag down performance (especially if we are able to convince them to [award hats for participating](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208248/191410) in the CV queue).

Comment: amount of filters seems to be [under 5K currently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209409/165773 "total amount of reviewers all time"), does this qualify as huge? Also, what about calculation? I mean, this info can be shown only to one who is currently reviewing (as at the [screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gQHyQ.png)), that makes it in the order of few hundreds doesn't it

Comment: This is the answer. Keeping cached values in memory and keeping them up to date isn't easy - and keep in mind that the counts would be *different for every active reviewer!* We actually had something less complicated in the old review system, and performance was still not good. Not saying it couldn't happen for a small set of filters, but someone would have to get clever for this to work for arbitrary filters.

Comment: @Shog9 thanks for explaining! What about [meta-tag:rate-limiting]? Say, as a reviewer, I'd be happy to see progress update once a day (preferably, once in an hour). I also don't have much interest to see info for short living filters, like those I setup only to quickly check if it's comfortable to work with

Comment: Yeah - so when I wrote "clever" I actually meant "willing to be wrong a good portion of the time", @gnat. Yes, it's possible. Whether it'd a good idea or worth the endless stream of questions regarding a number that's never accurate is another question.

Comment: @Shog9 understood, thanks!