# Show us how many posts are in our filtered Review Queues?

Tags: feature-request, review

I was thinking about some of the things said in [this post regarding the Close View Queue size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208220/158605) and how so many questions seem surmountable. You've already given us a way to break down that queue into smaller chunks by [allowing us to filter it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125169/158605), but we have no idea if the section we're trying to "clean up" is 3 posts or 30,000.

Could you add a number somewhere to the Review screen showing us how many posts there are to review in our filtered Review Queue?

(Ideally, a date range filter option would be nice too, to allow us to further break down the queue into manageable sizes for a single person to clear on their own)

**Edit:** Based on the success and some of the comments on [this event](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue?lq=1) when the Close Vote Queue was temporarily reduced in size and a post created to list the top Tags and Count of posts, I think this would help increase participation of reviewers in the Close Vote Queue a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What difficulties could be there to show amount of posts that match my filter in the SO CV queue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209632/what-difficulties-could-be-there-to-show-amount-of-posts-that-match-my-filter-in)

Comment: @gnat That one's a discussion, this one's a feature request... I'd say two different posts. This one's taking action on an idea, that was discussing it.

Comment: see also: [Easy close review queue filtering interface](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/easy-close-review-queue-filtering-interface/209778#209778)

Comment: @gnat Thanks, I wasn't aware that question was there! I think it's definitely relevant, but think this one has a higher chance of getting attention from the dev team since it's marked as a [feature-request] proposing the idea, instead of a [discussion] about if the idea is possible or not.

Comment: @hichris123 okay, retracted my vote

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can call me a credible or official source but if you skip that I have an answer that shows that you can partly already achieve what you want.

On the DataExplorer we have Posts, Tags and Votes, including close votes (VoteTypeId=6). I [created this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164744/closes-vote-count-per-tag-with-date)

```
select t.tagname , count(*) as cnt
from votes v
inner join posts p on p.id = v.postid
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where votetypeid = 6
and p.closeddate is null
-- and p.LastEditDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-02-28'
group by t.tagname
order by 2 desc
```

that returns for each tag the number of close votes.

I commented out a line for restricting the results on editdates of the post to give you an idea how you could take dates into account.

Do notice that this query can't differentiate on the close vote reasons used in the filter (like off-topic, Too Broad etc) because that data only becomes available in SEDE as soon as the post is closed.

The SE DataExplorer is refreshed every monday at 03:00 UTC so at worst the counts you are looking at are 7 days old.

Comment: Thanks rene, this is really useful for single users looking to accomplish this. But I brought this idea up as a feature-request on meta because I thought if implemented by SO, it would encourage more users to help out with the review queues, and could lead to a more permanent solution for managing our close-vote-queue :)

Comment: I really like the idea and I certainly don't want the SE-team to assume this feature-request is now solved by my nifty query. In the 6-8 weeks it takes for implementing your request on SO, users are free to use my workaround...  :-)