# Stats of close votes review queue for SO?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

Are there any stats (chart would be nice) for how the size of the review queue for StackOverflow has changed in time?

Currently it's about 52-53k, but I have impression it's growing slowly. I'm curious what is the trend, is it going to grow to infinity or it is steadily decreasing? My observations are from limited timescope, so they can be very inaccurate.

Comment: _To Infinity and beyond!!!!_

Comment: Data point: it was 48.6K on Feb 26 when I mentioned it in my community moderator nomination.

Comment: Another data point, it was above 60K in September or so when the queues started. So overall, it's not growing alarmingly, more like slowly decreasing.

Comment: Or it's a parabola.

Comment: The linked question has DataExplorer query unable to run because of timeout with any greater date scope, without it it's unreliable (many old questions are meeting the query). And the question, AFAIK, can land in queue because of flag, not necessarily close vote...