# Display the number of pending review tasks created in the past 24 hours for the Stack Overflow close review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

This is just depressing:

[image: 95.2K close votes]

And I *don't* mean it's depressing that there are that many questions that might need to be closed. There are nearly 6 *million* open questions on Stack Overflow - if under 2% of those are crap, we're doing *great*. Realistically, that number is probably going to get a lot bigger before we're done... But I'm working on another post about that, so enough said for now.

No, that number is depressing because *I can't do anything about it*. Ok, realistically **I** could - since I'm immune to the normal voting limits, if I spent the rest of my evening reviewing stuff I *might* be able to bring it down by... .1 or .2K. That's assuming my wife doesn't kill me first. But for most other folks reviewing stuff, there's literally nothing they can do that will affect that number. They can burn through their entire review limit, and it'll still be exactly the same.

That's depressing. And ***it's a lie.*** Those folks *are* helping, they *are* accomplishing something useful... The system just doesn't tell them this. And that's *wrong*.

So here's what I'm proposing: every time the background task that populates the queue adds another bunch of items to it, figure up how many pending review tasks are in there from the past 24 hours... And display *that* number. Yeah, it'll still be a pretty big number - but now we're talking 2-3 digits *at worst* rather than a progress-hiding abbreviation. And more importantly, with sufficient effort it'll be possible to watch it *go down*.

For informational purposes, I would keep the full backlog displayed on [the stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats).

This might eventually be useful for other queues (broken links...) but for now it's only really needed for close and only on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So you would still run the user through the entire 95.2K gauntlet of questions, if they were so inclined?

Comment: I would hope so, @Robert. Otherwise, [my other feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208287/allow-direct-linking-to-a-filtered-review-queue) is pretty pointless.

Comment: Either I literally saw that question count increase on this page, or I need to get more sleep...

Comment: I think I agree with this. Last weekend, a handful of the mods on Stack Overflow went on a massive flag-handling spree. The resulting smaller numbers really do make a difference in how it feels to dive into the queue.

Comment: It still seems so strange to me that people have this overwhelming need for the queue to approach zero, but if those people think this will help it seems like a reasonable approach.

Comment: If I understand this correclty, possible duplicate of [Show the number of items added today, not the total number](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202159/another-idea-for-close-vote-queue-rejuvenation-show-the-number-of-items-added-t).

Comment: @TimStone - When you look at all of the _other_ queues, not really that surprising. People see a crap meter that shows them helping with crap reduction and it makes them happy... If they can't see it is helping, though, you get the close vote queue...

Comment: Perhaps showing people the number of reviewed times where the outcome was consistent with their chosen action would be helpful in thy regard too?

Comment: Not quite, @Dukeling (unless I misunderstood that request) - I'm not interested in how many were added, I want to see how many recent (24-hours) are still *not handled*.

Comment: Possibly. I just think showing people that their efforts are bearing fruit is the first and foremost thing to get right. Seeing the queue grow larger is depressing - knowing you can't put a dent in _that_ number is demotivating. Showing you that you are making a (possibly bit) dent in what we think is the most important bit of that queue -  quite helpful. Not sure that a you-were-right-or-not meter would be beneficial here.

Comment: You guys are already working on a broken link queue?

Comment: @Shog9 - having the number of unhandled / total in last 24 hours shows  progress. Might be worth having both numbers (i.e. 123 left out of 1345 )

Comment: What, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/links/), @Bill?

Comment: @Oded I was so hopeful... :(

Comment: @Shog9 Wait, so only the questions that were actually added today that were handled? Does that make all that much sense? What's the chance of actually getting those questions? Any one user's reviews are *still* not likely to make any noticeable difference. In the linked suggestion, you can literally see the removed count increase for every review you do (which is way better, IMO, than doing one review and seeing that the number outstanding has actually *increased* by a few).

Comment: I think we need more posts today about the Close Votes queue.  Because, contrary to what I heard on TV in the 70's, eight is NOT enough.

Comment: Unless you're heavily filtering, @Dukeling, it's *extremely likely* you'll get recent questions.

Comment: I have one more planned, @Johnny....

Comment: So reviewing questions with votes older than 24h would be 100% guaranteed to not make any difference visible on the surface? Isn't that *even more* depressing? (you're not proposing displaying both numbers are you?)

Comment: @Shog9 You could very well be right. I just remember seeing plenty of older questions, but I guess either the last votes could've been cast more recently (no easy way to see as far as I'm aware) or I'm remembering wrong (I only filter on "off topic", no (all?) tags). To most of us it's just a black box (I don't like black boxes all that much); I would love a more open dialogue on the sorting algorithm (although I wouldn't mind a closed dialogue all that much, if I'm involved) (or more complex UI would also be grand - someone, possibly me, may have suggested that at some point).

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189093/can-we-know-the-rates-of-adding-and-reviewing-close-votes

Comment: If you do that, better change the title from just "Close Votes" to something like "Close Votes recently added", in my opinion. We don't want to lie, do we? :)

Comment: I would say, "questions/day" is reasonably honest and still short enough to go below the number, @Sha - I guess we could put something longer in the title tip.

Comment: @Shog9 yup, sounds like a good plan.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps rather than putting a positive spin on the size of the review queue we could spend a little more time thinking about practical measures to improve the functionality of the queue. Psychological validation is good, but not nearly as good as real improvement to the system.

Would you rather feel good about your contributions or be given better tools to make contributing easier?

Answer (score 3):

After further thought, some analysis, and some internal discussion... I don't think this is worth implementing.

At the current rate of review, the number would hover between 900 and 1200 throughout the day, higher some days than others. That's not *awful*, but it's less encouraging than I would want; furthermore, the chances of an individual reviewer seeing the number drop *while* he was reviewing aren't great.

[It's time for more drastic measures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199879/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut/209774#209774).