# When reviewing close votes, also display the answers

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close

When I review close votes of questions, I am curious to see the answers that some of these questions got. The reason for that is that sometimes I can get a better understanding of how to judge a question I'm reviewing when I also see an answer to that question. Can the whole question thread just be added after the question part?

Comment: Frankly I'm surprised people _still_ review questions close votes. The interface is bad for so many more reasons, it's unrewarding, it's time consuming and it's a lot less useful than other types of reviews for the site. Good work though. I thnk the suggestion is solid.

Comment: [Yes please](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186817/ideas-for-the-close-queue#comment573627_186817)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a bad idea. Questions shouldn't be closed or left open based on their answers. That decision should be made based on the question itself.

Sometimes really bad questions get really good answers (I won't pick on anyone by citing examples, but sorting all answers by score should find a few...), but that doesn't justify the questions being left open. They're still bad questions that don't belong on our site.

However, you do have one other option: editing the question to bring it into conformance with our guidelines. This is often the best solution if there *is* a real question buried in there somewhere and that's what the good answers are actually answering. Your edit can bring that out, fixing the question, and justifying leaving it open. But you'll probably want to open the full question page for this anyway.