# Allow us to additionally filter off-topic close reasons in the Close Vote Review Queue

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

Given the ever growing close vote review queue, I think it would help things along if we could streamline the filtering a little more.

At the moment we can filter by tag and by close reason, but off-topic has 7 sub-close-reasons. It may improve the workflow a bit to be able to narrow it down to one or two sub-close-reasons.

[image]

---

**There are [41,155 reasons to add this filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209404/165773). About half of all the CV review queue.**
Supporting data [provided by Shog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/209404/revisions):

[image]

Comment: Better yet, can't we just hoist one or two of those items *out* of the "off-topic" sub-heading? Certain ones don't really seem to fit the natural interpretation of off-topic, but are distinct problems with the state of the question.

Comment: @CodyGray That's a good point, but I didn't want the filtering idea to get wrapped into another argument/proposal

Comment: I don't disagree (I *really* dislike the new categories), but this seems to go against the reworking of the flag categories that was recently done.

Comment: I'd be happy if [su], [sf] and "belongs on another site" (and "other"?) were all grouped - they're strongly related, unlike the other 3 reasons.

Comment: there are **[61,745 reasons to add this filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209404/165773)**. 2/3 of all the CV review queue, apparently extremely diverse issues, are presented to reviewers as an unsorted pile - even to those aware about how filtering works. No wonder that reviews get stuck

Comment: See also [Can we have a “recommendation and off-site resource” filter for the Close Review Queue?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267691/456814) on MSO.

Answer (score 31):

I do like the idea.

For example I'd review general off-topic, custom off-topic, and belongs to other site but I don't like reviewing "please post SSCCE" and "minimal understanding" reasons.

Note, that it may help [reduce the close votes review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow) because it may attract some people to review things they want to (like me, for example)

Comment: love the point that each person can choose their type

Answer (score 6):

This kind of filtering would make a huge difference.

The worst kind of questions, and easiest to review (least time invested), are the infamous

**must demonstrate minimal understanding**.

They represent the "do my homework", "I haven't done any personal research", etc types. They are most deserving of being removed and least difficult to identify.

If I could filter by those, I could knock out 40 quickly, efficiently, and without being sloppy.

Comment: Not as easy as recommended a tool, library or off site resource, could do those in my sleep

Comment: *Really* suspicious this post is just encouraging people to review a certain filtered type of post like popcorn and get sloppy.

Comment: **Really suspicious**??? As in conspiring to cause harm suspiscious??? Are you arguing that these kinds of questions are not more obvious than others? Are you arguing that there is no merit to distinguishing between obvious, and blatant Q's that need closing and are easier to identify? Or are you arguing that **I'm conspiring to cause sloppy reviews?** I don't see you addressing what I've said, @djechlin. What I see is you sniping and down-voting me, as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to have this! In the meantime, I use SEDE as a workaround (has several limitations).

##### SEDE Workarounds and their Limitations

Limitation: If you really want the review tasks (instead of just querying for flags), you have to accept that SEDE refreshes on a weekly basis, so as the week goes on, many of the results of the query will have already been reviewed, and new review tasks won't show up until the next refresh.

Limitation: I'm not aware of any way to query for review tasks or close votes by a specific CloseAsOffTopicReasonType (or any CloseReasonType for that matter). Only flags seem to carry that information.

Approach #1: Query for flags with the desired CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId, then join with ReviewTasks having the same same PostId and in the active state.

Approach #2: Just query for flags. This gives more results (I just tried and got ~1.7k for flags and 0.6k for reviews-of-flags), and doesn't seem to suffer as much from becoming outdated throughout the week (not sure exactly why the number difference. My guess for the activity/SEDE-outdatedness-rate difference is because review tasks are more visible to people who like to do this sort of thing, and because review queues give badges).