# Resort the Close Votes Review Queue

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

The [Close Votes Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) has reached 75K. It increased from ~50K in the last two weeks.

I have a suggestion I would like to propose to resort the queue based on the amount of close votes.

So, if there are questions which already received 4 votes then move them up the queue so we only need 1 more vote to close them and remove them from the queue.

I *kind of* know how queues work and my suggestion *kind of* defeats the purpose of having a queue in first place, but I think one time sort would much help quickly get rid of a great amount of questions that could possibly be closed quickly.

I am not sure how difficult it would be to implement such a sort algorithm so I'll leave it down to the developers.

I think though it would help to decrease the size of the queue quickly.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195352/daily-close-votes-queue-limit/195827#195827

Comment: _"I am not sure how difficult it would be to implement such a sort algorithm"_ - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/135216

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards wherever I try to insert the `PostId` after `http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/` the page is not found :/ not sure why

Comment: Because it's a different table (probably) @mehow; these are votes so you can work out how many votes each post has. It would need to be joined to the review table.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167109/close-votes-policy-review) (briefly mentioned this in number 12).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Personally I think a new question with 4 votes should be before an old question with 1 vote.

Comment: I'm not arguing against that @Dukeling though I would say that an old question with one vote that is about to age away should maybe be prioritised over a question with 4 votes that has a few days left.

Comment: Even if we don't sort the items in the queue by votes, if we could add a filter for the number of votes similar to how we can filter for tags, close reason, etc.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Makes sense. Ok, an old question that doesn't have 100 views yet (thus votes don't age away yet, as far as I remember). Sorting purely on the first vote on a question that will age away might be a good idea.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194515/sort-order-on-close-vote-queue

Comment: As stated in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/209637) on the question that @Nathan mentioned, the review queue is already sorted according to the number of review tasks that have already been performed on that question. This is not perfectly identical to your request, but it's close enough for government work. This should possibly be closed as a duplicate of that question.