# Review close votes - filter questions by number of close votes

Tags: feature-request, review, closed-questions

A nice feature to bring down the Close votes review queue could be the ability to filter questions by the number of close votes they already received.

This way I could filter questions with 4 close votes already, which are (theoretically) much more likely to be a candidate for closing than a question with only 1 close vote. This would prioritize questions that more people found not fitting the format to get closed faster.

Thoughts?

Comment: I believe the selection for questions to show you in the queue *already* favours questions with the most close votes.

Comment: It could also encourage robo-reviews, with everyone assuming that if it has 4 votes already they might as well be closed even if they're not all that familiar with the question.

Comment: @PeterJ - Robo reviews are already encouraged by the badges you receive for reviewing. Infact that seems to be the main reason behind it.

Comment: @Matt Didn't know that - in the close reason dialog it often shows just 1 close vote.

Comment: @easwee: I can't guarantee this is the behaviour... I'm just very confident that I've seen this behaviour described somewhere! I'd try find a link, but I'm posting from mobile! Like I said... IIRC, it only *favours* posts... you'll still get the odd one thrown in... also, if you're using filters and tags etc, this will also affect the order of posts you get presented with.

Comment: @easwee: scratch that. Google foo still works from a phone; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194515/sort-order-on-close-vote-queue/199912#199912

Comment: @Matt Thanks for info. That question kinda summarizes my other thoughts about the review queue.

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand, you want to *leave open* some posts that don't necessarily have 4+ downvotes, don't you?

I think you should be reviewing each post regardless of the upvotes/downvotes it has, this is not always an indication on whether a post should be or shouldn't be closed.