# What's on with "edit your question" inside duplicates messages?

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

When a question is closed as duplicate, we get such message:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question, please edit this question to explain how it is different or ask a new question

Screenshot:

> [image: Example of closing message duplicate].

The part "please edit this question to explain how it is different..." makes me think several things:

- It suggest to edit the question, does it mean it can be re-opened?
- If yes, how this may be done? There is no mechanism for telling or advertising a OP that the question has been edited in a way it is not a duplicate, which means it can be re-opened only if a moderator see the question in the question list and want to take time to examine it.

I know I'm wrong on several points here, but I couldn't find the real purpose of this part of the message.

Comment: As the answer says, editing a question closed as duplicate place it a special queue where users with 3K rep and more can see it and vote to reopen. Either five such users or one diamond moderator can reopen it. In addition, editing bump the question to the front page where it gets new attention.

Comment: Please don't remove the tag, it means the question/discussion is about the close-as-duplicate mechanism. Don't stick to semantics.

Comment: @ShadowWizard : Yes, but as I said inside the edit history, it is about exact-duplicates not duplicates in general. Anyway, thanks for your edit.

Comment: You are clinging to semantics. The tag, even though named "X" is also about "Y".

Comment: description : *This tag is referring to the process of identifying and closing questions that are* **exact duplicates** *of another question.*

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, and this *is* a question related to the process of identifying an closing questions that are duplicates of another question.  Reopening questions that were erroneously closed *is a part of that process*.

Comment: @user2284570 there is no tag for "partial duplicate" and actually no such thing. The term "exact duplicate" is used to describe questions being closed as duplicate of other questions. If you disagree with the wording, feel free to suggest a fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions edited while they are on hold go into a reopen queue, so they *are* given attention by people capable of reopening them.  You do not need to hope that a moderator happens to see the question.

Comment: There are no "on hold period" for duplicates... Questions are closed immediatly (at least on meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: For the purposes of this feature, there is, there just isn't any graphical distinction.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228615/242800 as been asked yesterday and closed today without "on hold period". When you flag for a duplicate, the warning take form of an automatic comment ("possible duplicate... ")

Comment: @user2284570 As I said, it's not going to be graphically different, but with respect to how it's handled for this particular feature, it is treated as if it were on hold.  The fact that it doesn't say "on hold" is irrelevant, with respect to this particular question.  There is no need for the question to say "on hold" for edits to push it into the reopen queue.

Comment: Ok, does it really like other close-reasons (exept that the on old-message don't appear)?

Comment: @user2284570 Editing recently closed duplicate questions puts them in the close queue, as I have said in my answer.  What the close message looks like when reading the question is irrelevant.

Comment: What is the period for duplicates? I've just edited [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228615/242800), and the the reopen queue length is still zero...

Comment: @user2284570 Items are only added to the queue the first time they are edited.  If the close action is to keep it closed, then additional edits don't add it back into the queue.