# Why can't we list out the most close voted first at review queue?

Tags: discussion, review

Why can't we list out the most close voted questions first in the review queue? While reviewing duplicate questions I noticed that the least close voted questions (1 close vote) and the most close voted questions (4 close votes) get listed in no apparent order.

Why can't we sort the questions, starting from most close voted to least close voted? It would help to close questions sooner.

Comment: Why is this tagged review-audits?

Comment: The order is now random, as far as I know, no sort whatsoever.

Comment: Also any reason you don't use the period character and upper case letters?

Comment: "The queue already works this way... Sorta: the more previous reviews a given task has had, the closer to the top of the queue it'll be..." ([Sort Order on Close Vote Queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/165773))

Comment: If you have more than 10k reputation, the moderator tools provide a list of questions with the most number of close votes over the past X days.

Comment: @gnat that is kinda of old answer, maybe it's been changed however slightly? idk  ... OP- this did happen once on SO, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue

Comment: @CRABOLO my observations in SO close queue (~25K reviews so far) suggest that it works the way described over there