# To flag or not to flag as flags remain pending and/or age away

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

We all want stackoverflow to be a place where the community can/should get answers to well researched, non opinion based questions.

I have made a mission of flagging badly researched, opinion based questions so moderators and/or other users with more rep points can weed out poor questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444648/ux-button-design-and-basics).

For the most part this seems to work fine, however some of my flags are either dismissed or aged away, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198578/messaging-app-like-whatsapp) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742111/calculate-speed-using-proximitiy-sensor-of-android). In other cases the flags are deemed useful but the [*badly researched question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742111/calculate-speed-using-proximitiy-sensor-of-android) remains open.

So the question is, should I bother flagging these type of questions?

*Constructive criticism* **always** welcome!

Comment: 14 days after your close flag ages away system allows to re-cast it [as described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250496/165773). This means, it is considered generally okay to cast flags that may age away due to lack of proper attention: system is designed to let flagger bring it to attention of [meta-tag:review]ers yet again

Comment: @gnat I was not aware of the 14 day rule, thx for the tip. However it makes you wonder if the flag wasn't entertained in the first iteration, would it be looked at if re-flagged?

Comment: it _will_ be looked at, close queue prioritises in favor of "fresh" flags and votes ([explained in more details here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/165773)). It is only not guaranteed that reviewers will act on it, they may prefer to abstain of making decision

Comment: I should point out that of the 18 close flags you've cast since September, only 6 have aged away. The other 12 led to the closure and / or deletion of the post they were cast on, so you've been mostly effective with these.

Comment: (side note) since you appear to be mostly interested in Stack Overflow, consider that there is dedicated [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) (SOCVR) chat room where you can ask for advice, help and guidance on related matters