What determines the visibility/priority of review tasks?
Based on my observations, not all review tasks are created equal.
I have noticed that in the review queues, even though there are hundreds or thousands of possible review tasks the system could choose from, there are sometimes one or a few particular ones that are shown with a seemingly high priority.
If I go to Close votes or Reopen votes, then click Review tasks, which has the effect of loading a new task without marking the current one as skipped, often but not always, I will be shown the same task or small subset of tasks over and over, meaning the system finds these tasks have a high priority, at least to be shown to me.
This means that the system has some internal algorithm to determine which tasks are more likely to be shown, because the above would be almost impossible if they were picked at random.
Additionally, some tasks are quickly reviewed and closed/reopened from review, whereas others go for weeks and eventually expire. This would be unlikely if the queue operated entirely on a first-come-first-serve basis, as a real-life FIFO queue would.
In other queues, this is less apparent because if I view a task without clicking Skip, they will not be shown to anyone again for the next 3 or so minutes. But if I view a task, wait a few minutes, and then load a new one, the chance that I will get the same one is much more than if the tasks were picked at random.
My question is, what factor(s) determine the weight/visibility/priority of review tasks? Does the system take into account views on the question? Or questions with tags the reviewer is active in? Or the time the question was added to review compared to the time other questions were? Is the algorithm the same for all queues, or does Close votes work differently from other queues for example?

I'm pretty sure Shog9 said something about this but I can't find where atm. IIRC newer posts are prioritized and then posts that had recently a review task completed.

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194515/sort-order-on-close-vote-queue

Somewhat related recent feature request: Prevent reopen votes from expiring until a question is dequeued to improve experience for low-visibility queue items

Pretty sure the logic for populating these queues has changed a bit since I left, but... Someone reported pretty much this same behavior 7 years ago, and I laid out the possibilities for why they might observe it. Or if you prefer, tl;dr
