# Should moderators override the review queue for items they've acted on?

Tags: discussion, review, duplicate-questions, moderation

Should a moderator be able to unilaterally close a question, and then vote to keep it closed in the review queue (after two people voted to re-open)?

The question is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198726/tweaking-close-requirements-to-manage-the-close-queue), and Gnat indicates (in the tooltip to his comment) that a mod voting in such a way boots the question right out of the review queue.  I'm inclined to believe him, since Gnat's usually good about knowing such things, which makes me especially annoyed at this action.

And of course there's the question of whether this is even a dupe.  Does the fact that a question asked a year ago soliciting suggestions for close-vote queue fixes mean that no further feature requests are allowed, *ever again*?  Does anyone with an idea have to just toss it on the bottom of that heap and hope somebody notices?

The only reason I really care is because this question being closed prevents me from opening a bounty on it—something I decided to do after seeing that the close queue had grown past 100K questions.  Seriously, it's time to do something about this.  The close queue is growing faster than Jon Skeet's rep.  The close queue is expanding faster than the American Waistline.  I can do this all day...

Comment: The current close every idea regarding close review queue as duplicate is incredibly irritating. Im not sure what is aimed by it. Vague "o no"s should be closed as duplicates of it. Concrete ideas should not. You have my reopen vote

Comment: It's closed because it's a very specific idea that is only relevant to the size of the close queue. I've been leaving the ones that are *not* specific to the size open. In short, your idea is a temporary fix that would only be valuable until the size made it back down to zero. Therefore, yes, it belongs as an answer to the "problem" it is trying to fix.

Comment: `your idea is a temporary fix that would only be valuable until the size made it back down to zero`  Nonsense.  Utter, utter nonsense.  Give trusted users the ability to effectively drain the queue, and it may very well get drained.  Take away that power, and watch it grow right back up.

Comment: @animuson a system of 'problem answered with idea' would be a fine system. But it's not the system all other feature requests use. I don't see why the close vote queue should get special treatment.  Where are answers against the idea to go? Or suggested modifications? The comments?! *shudders*

Comment: `The comments?!` - I think Jeff Atwood just got some cold shivers.

Comment: @RichardTingle Normally it's not a problem, but when you get so many people rattling off a million ideas, trying to link them all together becomes impossible because everyone thinks they need a *separate* question for some reason. Then everyone gets it in their head that it can only be closed as a duplicate if it's the exact same feature request, but who can ever find that *exact* feature request in the mess of questions that are flooding the system? This issue is more popular and irritating, yes, but that doesn't mean we need a bunch of questions talking about the same thing.

Comment: And I should note, that while I was one of two who originally left that question closed, there were also [three others](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/22520) who left it closed in a separate review.

Comment: Ok.  Who's gonna start consolidating all the feature requests [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/favorites) into one neat question with 40 or 50 answers....

Comment: Which question are you asking?  Whether the dupe should be unduped, or whether the system should allow mods to prevent a question from being unduped?  In general, mods have broad discretionary powers that are binding, although there are a few amusing edge cases.

Comment: @TheGrinch - I'd welcome any good answers on either of those points.

Comment: @TheGrinch although the dupe part of this seems to me the more important half.  It seems ridiculous that all feature requests now have to be agglomerated into a year-old question.  I guess I'm one of the stubborn people who thinks that each new feature request needs "a separate question" -- I thought that was rather how Meta works.

Comment: Well, I've floated the issue in the Teacher's Lounge, but there's not much interest in it so, since I disagree with the closure, I'm going to exercise my binding vote and reopen it.

Comment: Much thanks, Robert.  Ha - looks like you got a hat for it :)

Answer (score 11):

If a moderator believes that, after the edit, and the close votes, and the review, the question should still remain closed, then yes, said moderator is entitled to vote to keep it closed.

A moderator is elected (or promoted) for a reason. It's because the community as a whole trusts them. As such, they get to make these decisions.