# How to handle ever-increasing number questions pending closure in the review section

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

Ever since I gained 3000 rep on SO, I've noticed that the [number of questions pending review for closure](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) has increased consistently. It must have been 2 or 3 months ago that I first got rep to start reviewing questions and I've noticed that number creep up from 50k to now almost 83k.

It's clear the number of questions pending more close votes is creeping up and there's literally thousands of questions that will never get touched but remain on the list. *Every single other section* of reviewable questions/answers stays low consistently.

How do we tackle the endless in-stream of questions with close votes?

I understand that it's common for a close vote or two to get slapped on a question and it gets left that way forever. Should we remove stale close votes that never ended up in an actual closure? Is SO prioritizing newer questions over old ones when you actually start reviewing those questions?

Maybe this isn't even an issue and I'm not seeing it. Let me know what your thoughts are!

Comment: Under certain conditions close votes do decay already

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow) for a related question

Comment: @RichardTingle True, but that still doesn't address the fact that it's still increasing steadily. I suppose that question is almost a duplicate... apologies, I didn't see that one when searching. The filtering is nice, but I'm trying to discuss if there's something we should do to address this if it's even an issue.

Comment: That's why I didn't vote to close this as a duplicate, it's brought up from time to time but no real solutions seem to have been implemented

Comment: We're working on a few ways to attack this problem. The gist of it is that the raw number of things in the queue isn't *necessarily* an issue, but it certainly presents a challenge when it comes to morale and motivation. Stay tuned for meta posts on this. Probably from Shog9, since I'm on vacation right now (this comment notwithstanding :)).

Comment: I've been thinking this ever since the new queues have been introduced. Maybe some kind of incentive for people who are already interested in reviewing would help? Say, incentivize 500 users to review 100 items each? Maybe with a silver badge? Or mute all but 1000 items each day?