# Please streamline VTC-as dupe in the review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I am trying to be a good sport and work on the close queue. Some days I use up all my votes, most days I don't. I hate to be a whiner, but there is a ton of clicking to agree with a possible dupe:

- read the question. Click the Duplicate link and read it. Sometimes click and read another dupe.
- click the Close button over with the Edit/Reopen/Skip etc
- Choose Duplicate
- choose which it is a dupe of and wait while it loads
- click Agree way at the bottom

I know this sounds like nothing but it adds up. And I have to hold things in my head like which possible dupe I am going to use.

I propose not to take away any of the existing buttons - that way you can still close as off topic even if it was in the dupe queue - but to **add a button on each Duplicates's tab** that says <kbd>Agree, question should be closed as dupe of this</kbd> and that means with one click I am off to the next one.

Please?

Comment: Yes please!  I often filter out duplicate close votes because of this, particularly when I'm on a tablet.

Comment: @BilltheLizard or on a phone.  VTC as Duplicate is one of the worst experiences on the mobile version of the site.  You can't make it much better on a phone, but you can at least improve the experience in review

Comment: Yeah, this gets my emphatic upvote as well.  I almost always skip the "Duplicate" votes beacuse of this, and never stopped to think how many others did the same.

Comment: To play Devil's advocate here, I've seen questions closed as duplicates from the review queue that were clearly not duplicates. It seems like once a single duplicate close vote was added to a question, people went along with it without checking if it was true. Making this type of close vote easier could lead to an increase in these bad closures. I don't have a good solution for addressing this, though.

Comment: @BradLarson the ui could track whether a close vote came organically (outside the queue) or the long way in the queue or the short way in the queue, and if a significant accuracy difference was detected, the shortcut could be removed, or only offered to users who meet some bar or another (already got the badge so nongrinder is my first thought on that.)