# growing up of flag queue

Tags: support, flags, moderators

There is a problem on reviewing of flags.

My flags are waiting over 7 days.

Is this pointing to that my flags are useless or moderation doesn't take care flag queue?

Comment: What kind of flags are they? Are they close flags?

Comment: Most of my flags are on off-topic questions and duplicates.

Comment: There are nearly 100,000 flags waiting. <sigh>

Comment: That's great to understand!

Comment: @MehmetInce This is a problem [we are taking seriously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195352/daily-close-votes-queue-limit/195355#195355) so hopefully it won't be a problem forever. Keep flagging! a few fall though the cracks but that doesn't mean we aren't looking at the rest (Any user above 3,000 reputation can review these flags and act upon them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your flags are taking a long time because they're close vote flags (off-topic, duplicates, etc).

Close vote flags don't go to a moderator - they add the question to the close vote queue.

The close vote queue is huge, so it's going to take a while before your flags are dealt with.

Comment: For reference, at the moment I have a close vote flag waiting from July, and several from August!