# How can we address the relative imbalance in the review queue lengths?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, review, winter-bash-2013, review-abuse

In an effort to <del>unashamedly pursue cool looking hats [like](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/do-the-swim) [these](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/robocop)</del> improve the quality of the glorious SO forums, it seems that whereas the *Close Votes* queue looks <del>my work inbox after spending so much time on SO during Winterbash</del> rather overwhelming, all the other queues seem <del>like my bank balance after Xmas</del> rather anemic.

As a result, I rather feel like any new posts which do make it into queues like *First Posts*, *Late Answers* et al get <del>gobbled up like a lone steak tossed to a pack of wolves</del> processed rather quickly, to the point where the post has already been <del>stolen by cretinous fellow hat snatchers</del> actioned by other esteemed members.

Would SE be open to any ideas on how to improve the Queue status quo, e.g. by
<del>deviously closing a few Close Vote posts and reflagging these as *Vote to Reopen* instead</del>, raising the bar on the *Close Vote* queue, whilst lowering the requisite counts on the less bloated queues?

Merry Winterbash!

Comment: Ha, see the full [one billion ideas to solve the close queue problem here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195352/daily-close-votes-queue-limit/195355#195355)

Comment: FWIW, this is *not* just a Winterbash thing. The only one that is ever (semi-reliably) non-empty besides CV is suggested edits.