# Displaying close review queue size according to category

Tags: support, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close, review-stats

There are 116K items on close review queue now. But I just wonder, what is the distribution of these items according to close reason categories?

Is there a way to see which queue have how much item, with sub-category counts (like sub-categories of off-topic) if possible? I am wondering the basic reason of that queue size, whether most of it is duplicate questions or too-broad questions etc.

Comment: Yeah, would be good stats to see, if it's available.

Comment: Is this something we could see with some SEDE magic? I'd be interested as well

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209778/165773