# Changing the filter in the close vote queue doesn't work when having gotten there through a link

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

Using a direct link to the close vote with filters, as presented in  [Allow direct linking to a filtered /review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208287/allow-direct-linking-to-a-filtered-review-queue)...

Trying to use "filter" when on that page doesn't work at all.

Can we either disable the filter button, or make it work?

### To reproduce:

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=google

> [image]

Okay, fair enough.

> [image]

Still with me?

> [image]

This is hard!

> [image]

I'm so confused...

> [image]

Woohoo! Close vote queue cleared! Oh, no, wait...

Comment: Wait, isn't it SO only feature? In such case think this better fits MSO :)

Comment: [Is it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close?filter-tags=google)? It was implemented for [so] and is only really useful there (at the moment?), but I assume it works everywhere. I might've been a bit on the fence regarding where to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed in the first [post-never-forget](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/what-happens-when-you-plug-a-ups-into-itself/231862#231862) build rev that goes out.

Comment: It doesn't appear to work very often (specifically the steps described in the question) (this has been released, right?). Every now and again the URL redirects to `/review/close/someQuestionID`, with the filter on (which doesn't appear to work - it shows questions not conforming to the filter), but more often than not it just does exactly what was described in the question. I guess it might have something to do with there not being any questions for the above filter.

Comment: @Dukeling should be working correctly now