# First preference to the questions in the Close Vote RQ under a tag where the user is familiar with that tag

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close, filtering

I am a bit familiar with these regex, bash, awk, sed SO tags. But the questions appeared first in the Close vote Review queue is not the ones with these tags.

Without knowing anything about the tags other than the above, how do I put a close vote on that type of questions?

So it would be better if the questions in which I'm familiar with to come first on the Review queue.

**In AU:**

> [image]

All i mean, in SO would be,

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When in the Close Votes Queue, select the `filter` link on top. From there you can add up to three tags, and you'll be shown only questions with those tags.

> [image]

Top review tags used to be shown on the `/review` page, as a shortcut to the filter, but those appear to have been since removed for some reason. [(relevant post)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856/248072)

Comment: wow, doesn't know about the filter option. Thanks :D

Comment: ...which is why putting it where you suggested it is a good idea. @AvinashRaj

Comment: @AndrewC did you mean the second screenshot?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The one in your question, yes. I'd suggest adding "up to 3 tags: " and a box, too.