# Let us filter all review types - especially using tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, review, suggested-edits

Someone will probably close this as having already been discussed and dropped, but I will propose it anyway.

It seems that one can now use some tags (the most used, presumably) for filtering the [close queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202261/231821).

I would still like to be able to actually filter (*actively, by choosing* any tags) **all** review queues.

FWIW, I gave up reviewing at S.O. because the reviewing that I really feel like doing involves content that I know something about. (**;-)**)

Yes, I know that there are plenty of posts that could use some reviewing & fixing independently of their technical content. But I prefer to concentrate on areas I am interested in and maybe know something about. So I generally stick to reviewing posts on smaller sites that are limited to such areas. *Mea culpa.*

Too bad, because there are no doubt posts on S.O. that hit my preferred areas, and that I might be able to help with. So let me ask the question, as I have not seen a good answer, so far (no doubt someone will point me to a long discussion about this with good answers; apologies for not being able to find it myself):

#### **Why can't we filter review-queue posts?**

*In particular, why can't we use* ***tags*** *to filter them?*

On S.O., why preselect particular tags for this purpose, even if they are the most used in the posts to be reviewed? *Why not let* ***users*** *choose the tags?*

I'm guessing that the reasoning is that you want to attack review queue size in general, and you are afraid that if reviewers stick to their favorite tags then less stuff will get reviewed overall. Is that it?

If so, I'm not so sure about that last part. The pool of "reviewers" is not static. *Giving users a choice* might just mean that some users (like me) who are not crazy about spending hours trying to put a dent in review queues for areas that they don't care much about will in fact *become active reviewers* for areas that they do care about.

Think about it this way: *Give users the choice* of whether they want to review generally, regardless of subject matter and their knowledge of it. Some will choose to *review, review, review* anything and everything they can get their hands on. I'm not sure that fewer will do that if you offer it as a *choice* instead of imposing it as the *only* reviewing possibility. Others will dip into reviewing where they think they know something about the content. Surely, *content is important*, even if form etc. are also important.

This problem (if it is a problem) would probably not exist if S.O. were split into umpteen little sites for particular interest areas. But it does exist (I think), because S.O. is a monster (a good monster, but a monster). I use S.O., but only by filtering it, typically using tags. You would have one more reviewer if I could filter also (e.g., using tags) for reviewing.

Answer (score 2):

But wait, doesn't it exist yet?

> [image]

you can review by tag in any review queue.

Comment: Where do you see that? I looked but didn't find it. And is this only for Close votes? I'm asking that we be able to filter **all** of the review queues - preferably even *before accessing any of them*, but at least be able to filter **any** of them after accessing it. Ideally, I want to be able to type some tags in the search field and see the review-queue totals updated accordingly. In a word: **filtering**.

Comment: @Drew any review queue.

Comment: Then I would like to see the use recipe. It's not clear to me how this is done. And why is it not just available at the top level, like the usual filtering by typing stuff into the search field?

Comment: @Drew click "review" > choose review queue (suggested edits, close votes, etc) > in the top bar `Review |  Suggested Edits  filter` click "filter"

Comment: OK, I see it now. Clunky. I shouldn't have to go through all of that. It should be possible to type **anything**, including (any number of) tags, into the normal search field, to filter across **all** review queues. That then becomes something I can use as a browser bookmark, for instance. But at least most of what I requested is available - thanks for the info. **Now it's just down to a clunky UI problem.**

Comment: @Drew yes, only up to 3 tags. but in **all** review queues. You can request the removal of 3-tags-limit.

Comment: My request is different: be able to filter normally, across all queues, using the `Search` field.