# What determines when/how 'by type' and 'by tag' are shown in the review queues?

Tags: support, review

The review queue home pages look pretty much the same across the Stack Exchange network. However, I noticed that on Stack Overflow the Close Votes and Reopen Votes review queues have an option to filter on the close reason (ordered by the most common one? I can't tell):

[image: Stack Overflow review queues]

and the First Posts review queue on Super User has an option to filter on tag (only [windows-10] is shown, I suppose that's the most common tag):

[image: Super User review queues]

Is there any (documented or not) logic when those options are shown? The post linked to by @rene mentions

> Currently it's enabled *only on Stack Overflow*. Note, that we have a big threshold (50) for how many outstanding reviews there must be with a tag or close reason in order for it to show up on the dashboard.
>
> Update Jan 3rd, 2017: As noted below, this is implemented - however, it cannot be enabled *for tags* on Stack Overflow, as [it will bring the site to its knees](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298541/tag-pages-and-review-pages-not-loading-properly).
>
> Close reason filters from /review are still operational, and tags as well on smaller sites (currently Super User and Ask Ubuntu).

I assume that's still up-to-date, but the type/tag filters are only shown when you have access to the queues so I can't check. Still, it's close enough to what I was looking for.

Comment: There is a Shog9 post some where or maybe a tavern transcript. There was at least a performance problem with one of those in the early stages. Here it is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/easy-close-review-queue-filtering-interface

Comment: Thanks, I'll dig into that. FWIW, [windows-10] isn't among my [favorite tags on Super User](https://superuser.com/users/442468/glorfindel?tab=tags), I only asked a single question about it.

Comment: Yeah, those are not personalized. I think it shows the tag with the most posts in that queue.