# How can I make a bigger dent in close vote reviews?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

I have 40 close votes per day, which I can go through in 15-20 minutes on reviews (or much less if I filter to opinion-based/too-broad).

The current close vote queue size is 90.7k. At 4 remaining normal user votes per close that's about 362,800 total votes needed.

This means every day, I can contribute 40/362,800 = 0.011% of the total work required to take care of that queue.

That seems... low. Is there some way I can make a bigger dent?

Also, are there statistics available that show, for a given day (or on average per day), the number of new items added to the close review queue, the number of votes on questions in that queue, and the number of users who typically participate in reviews (I know there's the stats site I just don't know how to make this query)?

Comment: You know, we could make a *huge* dent in `java` by just automatically closing all questions that contain the phrases "best practice" or "better in terms of performance".

Comment: I hate those questions, the answer is (almost) always; the Java virtual machine is very good at its job, let it do it. And "No holding a boolean as a char isn't a good idea"

Comment: SE team isn't ready to answer this question - [2 months ago they had a meeting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195827/165773), no progress has been noticed since

Comment: +1 because I have to upvote every post about the high close vote queue numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a desire to prevent people burning out by reviewing too much, so I'm afraid not.

However try not to think about it like that, I see you are heavily into the java tag so think about it as making that part of stack overflow better. Other people can deal with C and VBA etc. No one can save the whole world, but you can make your town better

Comment: I would think people would only review as much as they wanted to; I may be overestimating the general population's self-control.

Comment: Its like reading a story to someone, if every day you read a chapter and when they ask you to keep reading you say "you'll have to wait for tomorrow" you maintain the excitement of the story

Comment: The questions should really be - how long would it take, on average, for users to get burnt out and would the spike in votes lead to emptying the queue? If users are going to get through a few thousand in a few days, that could be a few months worth of votes right there (and if you're burnt out for a few months, you may have netted roughly the same number of votes as you would've otherwise). And the spike in votes may lead to emptying the queue, which may lead to motivation to keep it empty.