# Close review queue rep

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

From what I have read, StackOverflow is having a huge problem with close review questions. I just crossed over 400 rep on StackOverflow, and would like to help. I have been dismayed to find, however, that you can't until you have 3000 rep. Why is this? Could it be at least changed for a short time to fix this?

Comment: That'd be a short term fix to a long term problem.

Comment: Using this logic you'll let users with 1 rep to vote to close and delete, just because there are tons of bad question.

Comment: @gnat No, not at all. Your link is a suggestion that close reviewing should award rep. This question asks about lowering the rep threshold for close reviewing.

Comment: This'd be a long term problem in exchange for a short term fix. Closing questions is effectively deciding what is on- or off-topic for the site. I doubt very much there's a magic reputation where someone just knows and there are constant arguments even among higher rep users. However, I know there are a number of people at 400 who I wouldn't trust. This change could occasion a significant change in the direction the site takes. This might be positive, but I doubt it; my impression is that the lower the rep the less strict you are. No idea if that's borne out by any data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Determining whether questions should be closed is *hard*.  It takes a fair amount of experience with the site to effectively determine whether a question should be closed, and what it should be closed for.

Allowing users to review items in the queue without enough experience using the site to make effective judgement would cause more harm than good.  Having less reviews, but quality and effective reviews, is better than lots and lots of very poor quality reviews.

We learned this lesson well enough with several of the other queues.  Queues such as the first/last posts queue ended up causing way more problems than they solved for quite some time when they came out because of the shear number of inexperienced users not making quality reviews.

Comment: That's why we upped the rep requirement for the First Posts and Late Answers queues from 125 to 500, and now include review audits to catch robo-reviewers.